# How to read TXT Records longer than 255 characters in correct order

Tags: dns, dkim, dnsjava

I am using [DNSJava](https://github.com/dnsjava/dnsjava) lib to fetch DKIM TXT records for a given selector + domain name. I want to ensure I read the record in the correct order when the record size is greater than 255 characters and spans over multiple strings in the result. As per the [RFC Doc](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7208#section-3.3) & [RFC DOC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-3.6.2.2) we should concatenate all the strings in the result, but it does not tell us if the DNS Server will return the record strings in the correct order.

Eg : "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUI5E9hZhMEEgjqF6fHNYYBmAEcF7DN2v/FA6yiY/a3R2L8ebGQjCdP2m3PfqLk8ovVd84eJ", "FkNuXGEsR0rXEHveOjc161z1tz4TGzPC5pGmjuzlYaibUQAb8T1GLbRse+ZkXhCxudeeRj7NBbCjaH1biClbp4v4/V0PLdugeGQQIDAQAB", "juzlYaibUQAb8T1GLbRse+ZkXhCxudeeRj7"

In the above example, I have no way to determine the order of records. Only DKIM header portion can be inferred to be start of a record

Comment: The order doesn't have to be determined - it's well-defined.

Comment: @CherryDT Do you want to say that DNS servers return the records in the correct order and the application only needs to concatenate the result?

Comment: Yes and no, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The order of those strings doesn't have to be determined, it's well-defined](https://serverfault.com/questions/776463/what-order-do-split-txt-records-get-assembled-in). Note that the strings you showed aren't *records* though!

You seem to be confusing different strings in the same TXT record with multiple TXT records. You cannot split a string across multiple records, but you *can* split it across multiple fragments within the *same* record, and this is probably what you are referring to.

A TXT record can contain multiple strings, see [RFC 1035](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#section-3.3.14):

```
3.3.14. TXT RDATA format

    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    /                   TXT-DATA                    /
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+

where:

TXT-DATA        One or more <character-string>s.

TXT RRs are used to hold descriptive text.  The semantics of the text
depends on the domain where it is found.
```

As you can see, the order of the strings is part of the record's RDATA itself. A DNS server isn't supposed to mangle it in any way.

For instance, this is how your example record would be defined in a zone file:

```
name IN TXT ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUI5E9hZhMEEgjqF6fHNYYBmAEcF7DN2v/FA6yiY/a3R2L8ebGQjCdP2m3PfqLk8ovVd84eJ"
             "FkNuXGEsR0rXEHveOjc161z1tz4TGzPC5pGmjuzlYaibUQAb8T1GLbRse+ZkXhCxudeeRj7NBbCjaH1biClbp4v4/V0PLdugeGQQIDAQAB"
             "juzlYaibUQAb8T1GLbRse+ZkXhCxudeeRj7")
```

...while multiple TXT records would look more like this:

```
name IN TXT ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUI5E9hZhMEEgjqF6fHNYYBmAEcF7DN2v/FA6yiY/a3R2L8ebGQjCdP2m3PfqLk8ovVd84eJ"
             "FkNuXGEsR0rXEHveOjc161z1tz4TGzPC5pGmjuzlYaibUQAb8T1GLbRse+ZkXhCxudeeRj7NBbCjaH1biClbp4v4/V0PLdugeGQQIDAQAB"
             "juzlYaibUQAb8T1GLbRse+ZkXhCxudeeRj7")
name IN TXT "google-site-verification=abcde_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
name IN TXT "MS=ms1234567"
```

In the latter case, you cannot be sure in which order you'll get those three records returned (`v=DKIM1...`, `google-site...` and `MS=...`), but it shouldn't have any meaning anyway.

In case of `dnsjava`, you should get an array with the different records (not necessarily in any order) from [`getAnswers`](https://javadoc.io/static/dnsjava/dnsjava/3.4.0/org/xbill/DNS/Lookup.html#getAnswers--), but for each record you should get its strings (**in order**) from [`getStrings`](https://javadoc.io/static/dnsjava/dnsjava/3.4.0/org/xbill/DNS/TXTRecord.html#getStrings--).